# The Machzeh Einayim on crying

Tags: sources-mekorot, mussar-ethics, parts-of-the-body

In the book [*With Hearts Full of Love*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422608913.html) on page 300, Rabbi Mattisyahu Salomon states the following:

In *Machzeh Einayim* the sefer asks, *"Why is that the Creator constructed people in such a way that no matter what part of the body is injured it is the eyes that cry? If your hand hurts, your hand should cry? If your foot hurts, your foot should cry. Why is it that when any part of the body hurts it is the eyes that cry?*

The answer is that your eyes are the magnets to *aveiros*.

Does anyone know where the Machzeh Einayim says this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter 3 (p. 46 [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33282&hilite=e5aefc63-a57f-4904-9d22-2d4f828904ff&st=%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D&pgnum=40)):

> ונתבונן כי אם יבכה האדם מרוב מכאוביו 
>   ומרוב צרותיו אז יזלו מים מעיניו, על מה עשה ה׳ ככה כי ירדו מים מעינים
>   ולא מאברים אחרים, אם יד או רגל או אבר אחר נלקה, העינים מורידים דמעות,
>   מפני מה העינים יבכו בעד כל אברי הגוף, כי הוא זה מפני כי עיני האדם המה
>   ראשית לכל חטאת, ובעבור חטאותיו בא האדם במצוקותיו, ולכן בעת כי יצר לאדם
>   ורע ומר לו העינים  מורידים דמעות, כי הם המה הביאו על האדם את כל הרעות
>   וכל הצרות, וזה דבר הכתוב פלגי מיס ירדו עיני על לא שמרו תורתך (תהלים
>   קיט). . .
>
> And let's consider that if a person cries due to all of his pains and
>   hardships water streams from his eyes. Why did Hashem make it this way
>   - that water would fall from the eyes and not from other body parts? If the hand, foot, or other limb are hurt the eyes produce tears. Why
>   should the eyes cry for all other parts of the body? It must be*
>   because the eyes are the genesis of all sin (*chatas*), and by sin one
>   gets in trouble**. And therefore when a person has it very hard his
>   eyes produce tears, for they brought upon the person all of the pain
>   and hardship. And this is [the meaning of] the verse "My eyes drop
>   rivers on account of not keeping your laws" (*T'hilim* 119). . .

(Translation and its punctuation are mine. The quote is from the original. I don't know the book. I just searched for crying and this came up.)

---

* An allusion to [*Sh'mos* 22:8](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%97)

** Translation help needed here.